# How to batch rename files to new name listed in Excel using Windows commands?

Tags: batch-file, command, rename, filenames

I have a lot of files that I need to rename.
The current filename is typical like `10002414892.PDF`.
The new name is a document number typical `170668-R-UP011-VA01-0205`.
No number sequence just a lot of different titles.
I have a two column list in Excel with the current file name and the new file name.

I need a command to rename the file from the current file name to the new file name.

Comment: Batch without additional help by WSH cannot read excel files. Will be a big effort for you to save the excel file as csv and paste the except here.The excel itself offers such option -> `Save as` ...

Answer (score 0):

I would use powershell but save the excel file as a CSV, the command for rename is

```
Rename-Item test.txt new_name.txt
```

then the load cmd is something like

```
$FilePath = "C:\Files\NewFileList.csv"
$serverList = Import-Csv $FilePath 
    -Header "OldName","NewName"
$serverList | where {$_.OldName -like ".PDF" } | Rename-Item OldName NewName
```